# How to add a div tag after a specific field?

Tags: 7

I have a view with four fields: *title, body, poster, podcast*.

I want to **add a div tag after poster field**. How can I do this?

Comment: make a custom view file and add whatever you want.

Comment: or alternatively you can add custom php filed

Answer (score 0):

You can simply rewrite result of poster field (it's in poster field settings), but you need to display fields, not content. Just add there poster token and div

Upd: ong, what am I about. If you display fields in your view, you can add custom Global text field. And write there custom html, remember to use php filter(works 100%, mb one another works too).

Answer (score 0):

Use the **Rewrite Results** in your View in combination with a [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token). That way you can customize your field's output to your needs. To do so:

1. In your *View*, within the *Fields* area, click on the desired field. E.g. *Poster*
2. Click on *Rewrite Results* and check *Rewrite the output of this field*. So, assuming that your field's machine name is *field_poster*, you just have to add its corresponding token and your div where desired. E.g.

[image]

As you can see, in the **Replacement Patterns** area right below you can find all the available tokens in your View, so change accordingly.

*Note that I'm assuming your View allows Fields (since it's not specified in your answer), which is required to use these instructions.*